# Replace the first Occurrence of { and anything before { with a single { in Informatica using REG_REPLACE

Tags: informatica

I have a requirement where I have an incoming string with curly braces in it. I have to replace the first occurrence of the curly brace and anything before with just one curly brace. In short i have to eliminate anything before the first occurrence of a curly brace using REG_REPLACE in Informatica. I tried using s/^[^{]*// as in sed in UNIX but it didnt work at all. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm sed doesnt really have concept of greedy or lazy replacement, better to use very similar but more robust perl replace command. Also your sed command is trying to replace the start of the line then first character so long as it isnt a curly brace and then everything else with blank.

Try

```
perl - pi -e 's/^*?{//g' addyourfilenamehere.
```

Using informatica is also possible using instr to find the position of the first { character and then substr to extract all characters after that character into another port similar to what nico suggests here https://network.informatica.com/thread/16336

You'd have a variable integer port lets call FIRSTBREAK set to

```
INSTR(FIELDIN,'{') + 1
```

and your output port set to

```
SUBSTR(FIELDIN, FIRSTBREAK)
```

I personally avoid regular expressions in coding, the are wuite powerful but I've found a number of messes due to unexpected regex behaviour

Comment: That's a great answer. Regexps are great, but this one can be handled by simple built-in functions. And simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!  Yes, I have used similar expression to that. 
Output Port= SUBSTR(INPUT_STRING, INSTR(INPUT_STRING,'{'), LENGTH(INPUT_STRING))